# Socket.io/WebSockets continuously reconnecting — issue with Nginx proxy configuration?

Tags: sockets, proxy, nginx, websocket, socket.io

I am using Socket.IO in my Node.js application. Today I deployed it for the first time, and I noticed that my sockets keep reconnecting. I have "connect" and "disconnect" logging to the console in the respective socket events, and this is the result:

[image]

What's more, it seems that the polling technique is being used, when my browser is surely modern enough to use WebSockets — so I believe this is a configuration issue. WebSockets work fine when I am running the Node.js in development with no proxy in the middle.

This is my Nginx configuration, which serves as a proxy to my Node.js server:

```
upstream reader.oliverjash.me {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name reader.oliverjash.me;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/reader.oliverjash.me.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/reader.oliverjash.me.error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    proxy_pass http://reader.oliverjash.me;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

I believe that the lines:

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

are significant in enabling WebSockets (as per [this reference/tutorial](https://chrislea.com/2013/02/23/proxying-websockets-with-nginx/)). Before I added these, WebSockets did not work at all with the proxy. Now I seem to get polling, which is better than nothing.

My Nginx version is 1.4.0 stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was because I had clustered my Node apps. Added Redis as a memory store for Socket.IO and that solved all of my problems! http://adamnengland.wordpress.com/2013/01/30/node-js-cluster-with-socket-io-and-express-3/